# primeNg get Nodes attribute

Tags: angular, primeng-treetable

I have this json output :

```
{
"data":
[
    {
        "label": "The Avengers",
        "data": { "name" : "The Avengers", "type" : "book"},
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "leaf": true
    },
    {
        "label": The Ring",
        "data": { "name" : "The Ring", "type" : "movie"},
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "leaf": false
    }
]
}
```

In my template, i want to get the value of the leaf and the expandedIcon attributes for each node, but i dont see how to do it :

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode"></p-treeTableToggler>
        {{rowData.title}}
      </td>
      <td>{{rowData.type}}</td>
      <td>{{rowNode.leaf}}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```

The rowNode.leaf is empty. How to get his value ? because i didn't see an exemple in the documentation

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
  <td>{{rowNode.node.leaf}}</td>
```

**[some reference](https://github.com/sourabh8003/ultimate-primeNg/blob/10b8843b4d21e2b26d8718c6a12281b9184e3a0a/src/app/components/treetable/treetable.ts)**